# Codeigniter - How to get the column name for which the duplicate value was provided

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I have a table with multiple unique fields:

```
table structure
---------------
| id (primary) | key_1 (unique) | key_2 (unique) | key_3 | key_4 (unique) |
```

and so on

On using `db->insert()` or `db->update()` methods of Codeigniter query builder class, I may get any number of values that are not unique. Say values provided for `key_1` and `key_4` are duplicate.

Codeigniter's `db->error()` gives me `{code: 1062, message: "Duplicate entry 'xyz' for key 'key_1'"}`.

Is there any way for me to pull out the **names** of the **table fields** for which the error was raised without performing some substring gymnastics on the error message?

Current method:

```
$error = $this->db->error();
if ($error['code'] == 1062) {
    $key = '';
    $message = $error['message'];
    $needle = "'";
    $lastPos = 0;
    while (($lastPos = strpos($message, $needle, $lastPos)) !== false) {
        $positions[] = $lastPos;
        $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
    }
    $count = count($positions);
    $length =  $positions[$count - 1] - $positions[$count - 2];
    $key = substr($message, $positions[$count - 2] + 1, $length - 1);
    if($key == 'key_1') {
        // value for field 'key_1' exists in the table
    }
}
```

Comment: Do some `SELECTs` to find the values that already exist?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Seems counter-intuitive, one of the reasons I add unique constraints on the column is that I shouldn't have to do that exactly before every insert/update.

Comment: Well, I don't think a DB is going to return a machine-readable response to an insert, so you need to do the work.  Or look at your schema - I'm trying to think of a case where I've had more than 1 unique field in a single table (besides PK) ... could/should they all be in different tables?  Is it  some kind of UI where users are adding records?  If yes, do some validation before getting to the insert stage - the validation can show the user on the front end which fields are dups.